# How to use Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent on running Thead.Principal?

Tags: c#, windows-authentication

When a console application starts, `Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.IsAuthenticated` is false and `System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().IsAuthenticated` is true.

How does one set the Thread's `CurrentPrincipal` to that of the principal of the current `WindowsIdentity`?

I don't want impersonation, but to simply set the console's thread to use the identity of the current Windows user.

```
System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity currentUser = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();

Console.WriteLine($"Windows Authenticated: {currentUser.IsAuthenticated}");
Console.WriteLine($"Thread Authenticated: {Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.IsAuthenticated}");
```

Comment: It is very unlikely that the main thread is running in any security context other than that of the current user.  Probably `Thread.CurrentPrincipal` returns some sort of default or empty instance if the thread isn't currently impersonating.

Comment: Right, so currentUser is authenticated, why isn't Thread's CurrentPrincipal?  And how do I make it so, without asking the current user his username and password? Is it required to do impersonation? I can't just leech off current user?

Comment: Best guess, because the thread doesn't *have* a CurrentPrincipal (and is probably not supposed to).  Apart from the fact that `.IsAuthenticated` isn't giving you the result you were expecting, have you experienced any actual problem?  Everything should just work - when a thread has no security token attached, the security context of the process is used instead.  It's all automatic, you don't need to do a thing.

Comment: Yes, it does just work. But is there no way to have the Thread "inherit" the security of the Process, which is already authenticated as the Windows user, or as the runas user? Perhaps I need to launch a new thread in Main() and pass it the security context of the process?

Comment: You could try calling `WindowsIdentity.Impersonate(System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity)`, but I really don't understand what you're trying to achieve.